# Ошибки установки ч/з CPAN Win32::Exe

Tags: perl

Доброго времени суток!

При установки, используя CPAN, модуля Win32::Exe (Perl 5.16) выполняется тест (dmake test) и при этом возникает ошибка... Подскажите, люди добрые, как от нее избавиться?

```
Failed test 'use Win32::Exe::InsertResourceSection;'at t/0-load.t line 6.Tried to use 'Win32::Exe::InsertResourceSection'.Error: Can't load 'C:\Perl516\cpan\build\Win32-Exe-0.17-cT9GUT\blib\arch/auto/Win32/Exe/InsertResourceSection/InsertResourceSection.dll' for module Win32::Exe::InsertResourceSection: load_file:Неверна  попытка доступа к адресу пам ти at C:/Perl516/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 191.at (eval 4) line 2.Compilation failed in require at (eval 4) line 2.BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 4) line 2.Looks like you failed 1 test of 1.t/0-load.t ... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100) Failed 1/1 subtests t/1-basic.t .. t/1-basic.t .. 1/1 # Failed test 'use Win32::Exe::InsertResourceSection;'at t/1-basic.t line 6.Tried to use 'Win32::Exe::InsertResourceSection'.Error: Can't load 'C:\Perl516\cpan\build\Win32-Exe-0.17-cT9GUT\blib\arch/auto/Win32/Exe/InsertResourceSection/InsertResourceSection.dll' for module Win32::Exe::InsertResourceSection: load_file:Неверна  попытка доступа к адресу памяти at C:/Perl516/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 191.at (eval 4) line 2.Compilation failed in require at (eval 4) line 2.BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 4) line 2.Looks like you failed 1 test of 1.t/1-basic.t .. Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100) Failed 1/1 subtests
```

Comment: А не 64-х разрядной ли системе это запускается?

Comment: Нет, на 32-разрядной! ОС Windows 7...